Discriminant of a matrix with respect to change of basis
According to "Commutative Ring Theory" by Matsumura:" If $A$ is a finite $k$-algebra, the trace of an element $\alpha$ of $A$ denoted by $tr_{A/k}(\alpha)$ is the trace of the $k$-linear mapping induced by multiplication of $\alpha$. Let $w_1,....w_n$ be a linear basis of $A$ over $k$. Then $d=det(tr_{A/k}(w_iw_j))$ is called the discriminant of $A$ over $k$."
It is also written that if $s_1,.....s_n$ is another set of basis of $A$ over $k$, then if $s_i=\sum (c_{ij})w_i$ then the discriminant with respect to this new basis is $det(c_{ij}).d$.
Now I am just trying to check whether statement is true for just $n=2$, but I am unable to do so. I was wondering if anyone can help me with this problem.

Let $W = \begin{pmatrix}w_1 \\ w_2 \\ \vdots \\ w_n\end{pmatrix}$ $S = \begin{pmatrix}s_1 \\ s_2 \\ \vdots \\ s_n\end{pmatrix}$ and $(c_{ij}) = C$
Now $WW^{T} =\begin{pmatrix}w_1w_1 & w_1w_2 & \ldots & w_1w_n \\ w_2w_1 & w_2w_2 & \ldots & w_2w_n \\ \vdots & \vdots & &\vdots \\ w_nw_1 & w_nw_2 & \ldots & w_nw_n\end{pmatrix}$
Let's denote the matrix $(tr(w_iw_j))$ by $tr(WW^{T})$  so that discriminant = $\det (tr(WW^{T}))$
But now $SS^{T} = (CW)(CW)^{T} = CWW^{T}C^{T}$ hence $tr(SS^{T}) = tr(CWW^{T}C^{T})$
But since trace function is $k-$linear, what we get on R.H.S. is just $C \cdot tr(WW^{T})\cdot C^{T}$
Finally after taking determinant you get discriminant w.r.t. new basis as $(\det C)^2$ times discriminant w.r.t. old basis. Note that there is square of determinant of $C$ here and not just determinant as in your question. Also, some things in the answer probably need to be precise and rigorous, however this should give you a picture of where this relations is coming from.

Sorry I am a bit confused about the initial assumptions, you are saying $(tr(w_iw_j))$ is $tr(W_1W_2)$, However, that itself has a definite value in $k$, whereas on the left hand side there is a matrix.

Both the terms you mentioned in the comment are matrices and they are same. The later is just for notational simplicity. What I am saying, try it for 2×2 case. That way you should get it.
